# Trying to display ion-label using ngIf

Tags: ionic4, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to use ngIf and ngModel.

I have made a simple question, if the answer is yes I'd like to display another label, if the answer is no, nothing happen.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Testing ngIf ?</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="sel" >
    <ion-select-option> YES </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option> NO </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-label *ngIf="sel == 'YES'">TEST</ion-label>
```

However, when I select Yes nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed value of ion-select-option. Please try this -

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Testing ngIf ?</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="sel" >
    <ion-select-option value="YES"> YES </ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value= "NO"> NO </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-label *ngIf="sel === 'YES'">TEST</ion-label>
```